# How can I write this in Vanilla JS: $(function() {...}?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how to write `$(function() {...}` in vanilla JS. However, bc it looks like Google doesn't let you search the dollar sign, I can't find it. I do know how to do $(document).ready(function{...}) in vanilla, but how does one do $(function() {...} in vanilla js?

Comment: do you mean getting to select elements like so? `$(element)`? @AviG

Answer (score -2):

```js
function stuffToDo() { ... }

// If we're already past the "DOM is ready" point, execute immediately:
if (document.readyState === "interactive" || document.readyState === "complete") {
  stuffToDo();
}

// Otherwise, wait for DOMContentLoaded to fire:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", stuffToDo, { once: true });
```

Comment: this question is a dupe

Comment: I don't think that justifies downvoting the answer; if you want to downvote the question, go ahead.